Discord Bot Freezes and Stops Sending/Receiving Audio Buffers
I'm working on a Discord bot that connects to a voice channel, listens to the audio, and sends it to a WebSocket server. Initially, everything works fine, but after some time, the bot freezes and stops sending/receiving audio buffers.  After a certain period, the bot stops processing audio. There are no errors thrown, but the audio buffers stop being sent and received.   Here are the key parts of the code I use to handle the connection and audio processing:
let count = 0;

    await entersState(connection, VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, 30000);
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    connection.subscribe(player);

    ws.on('open', () => {
      voiceChannel.members.forEach(member => {
        if (member.user.id !== client.user.id) {
          member.voice.setMute(false);
        }
      });
    });

    ws.on('error', console.error);
    ws.on('close', () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection closed, attempting to reconnect...');
    });

    const audioBuffers = new Map();

    connection.receiver.speaking.on('start', userId => {
      audioBuffers.set(userId, []);

      const opusStream = connection.receiver.subscribe(userId, {
        end: {
          behavior: EndBehaviorType.AfterSilence,
          duration: 1000
        }
      });

      const pcmStream = opusStream.pipe(new prism.opus.Decoder({ rate: 48000, channels: 2, frameSize: 900 }));
      const wavStream = new PassThrough();

      ffmpeg(pcmStream)
        more filters
        .pipe(wavStream);

      wavStream.on('data', chunk => {
        const chunks = audioBuffers.get(userId);
        if (chunks) {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        }
      });
    });

    connection.receiver.speaking.on('end', userId => {
      const chunks = audioBuffers.get(userId);
      if (chunks && chunks.length > 0) {
        const audioBuffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        const duration = audioBuffer.length / 48000 / 2;
        if (duration > 1.0) {
          console.log('Sending audio buffer:', audioBuffer);
          ws.send(audioBuffer);
          audioBuffers.delete(userId);
        }
      }
    });

    ws.on('message', data => {
      const channelEvent = voiceChannel.id === spanishVoiceChannel ? 'dataReceivedEnglish' : 'dataReceivedSpanish';
      eventBus.emit(channelEvent, data);
      count++;
      console.log(`${count}:`, data);
    });

    return player;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error joining voice channel:', error);
  }
}

What I Have Tried

Monitoring Connection Status: Added logs and intervals to check the status of the WebSocket and voice connection.
Handling Errors and Reconnections: Implemented reconnection logic for both WebSocket and voice connection.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.
